# Why are my VMs showing 2% CPU usage on the guest but shows 30% CPU usage on the host while idle?

Tags: windows-10, virtualbox, cpu-usage

I have the following setup:

1. Fully updated, freshly installed Windows 10 64bit on Lenovo W550s laptop. It is running VirtualBox version 5.2.18 r124319 with extension pack.
2. Fully updated, freshly installed Windows 10 64bit guest VM on 100GB dynamic disk. It has VirtualBox guest additions installed.

While the VM guest sits idle consuming only 2% CPU, but the host sees 30% consumed by vbox. Please see screenshot below:

[image: wasted CPU in virtualbox]

So how can I go about diagnosing this, and what would be recommended fixes to try?

FWIW, It remains like this constantly. It is not just a momentary peak but a continuous problem.

Comment: Why do you think this is a problem?  It takes resources to run a VM, even if it isn't doing much

Comment: I think it should not need more than a full core at 100% to run an idle VM. I use vbox often, this never happened before.

Answer (score 2):

This is 3D acceleration problem. Switch on acceleration in Display tab settings for virtual machine.

Comment: Hi! I am no longer able to test this, but sounds legit! :)